# Zermelo-Fraenkel union axiom

Tags: set-theory

On the following [website](https://www.britannica.com/science/set-theory/Axiomatic-set-theory) there is a table listing the ZF axioms for sets.

I am confused with the axiom of union, namely:

> If $C$ is a set, there exists a set $A$ such that $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in B$ for some member $B$ of $C$.

Can anyone show a concrete example of this? I do not understand at all what this means. I suppose $A$ is the resulting union, but I am confused as to how it manifests since I am trying to understand this based on my understanding of the usual union of two sets.

Comment: The axiom of Union simply states $\bigcup C$, a union of *all* elements of $C$, exists for any $C$.

Comment: Example: If $C=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3,4\}\}$, then the axiom says that $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ exists. The axiom forces $1\in A$ because for $1\in B=\{1,2\}\in C$. It forces $5\notin A$ because $5\notin B=\{1,2\}\in C$ and $5\notin B=\{2,3,4\}\in C$.

Comment: The union of two sets $B_1,B_2$ would be the set $A=\bigcup\{B_1,B_2\}$.

Comment: Maybe this would be more explanetory if the article stated that $C$ is a set of sets that are intended to be unioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the collection of sets you intend to union: 
$$  C = \{ \{0,1\}, \varnothing, \{0,1,2\}, \{\text{red}, \text{green}\}\}  \text{.}  $$
$A$ is the union of the elements of $C$ exactly when each element of $A$ is an element of some element of $C$: $1 \in A$ because $1 \in \{0,1\} \in C$.  By this prescription, $A = \{0,1,2,\text{red}, \text{green}\}$, is the union of the collection of sets, $C$.

Comment: I was confused with the usage of the word *some* in "for some member $B$ of $C$". It seems as certain members $B \in C$ are excluded when in fact we are considering every $B \in C$. What do you think?

Comment: @MichaelMunta : Yes, we allow $B$ to range over every element of $C$.  Although there can be more than one, it is enough that, for each element $x \in A$, there is one assignment of $B$ to an element of $C$ to exhibit $x \in B \in C$.  We are free to use a different assignment of $B$ for each element of $A$.  A way to capture this freedom is "for each $x \in A$, there is a $B_x \in C$ such that $x \in B_x \in C$."

Comment: And what about a set for example $C = \{1,2,3\}$? A union for that is not defined, only for a collection of sets?

Comment: @MichaelMunta : I believe you are thinking the right way; the definition only claims the existence of the union of the elements of $C$ that are sets.  Your example has a potential complication -- "$1$", "$2$", and "$3$" may be abbreviations for sets.  If they are, then $\{1,2,3\}$ is an abbreviation for a collection of sets and it would be sensible to take their union.  But without a pre-existing discussion of using "$1$", "$2$", and "$3$" as such abbreviations, I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Students are usually familiar with $\cup_{j\in J} A_j$ when $A=\{A_j:j\in J\}$ is an indexed family of sets. That is, $x\in \cup_{j\in J}A_j\iff \exists j\in J\,(x\in A_j).$

When we write $A=\{A_j:j\in J\}$ we mean there is a function $f$ with domain $J,$ but we have written $A_j$ for $f(j),$ and that $A=\{f(j):j\in J\}.$

But we do not need to describe $A$ as the image of a function $f$ in order to define $\bigcup A=\{x:\exists B\in A\, (x\in B)\},$ although if $A=\{A_j:j\in J\}$ then $\bigcup A=\cup_{j\in J}A_j.$

To define what an indexed family is, you must define what a function is: a certain kind of set of ordered pairs, so you must also define an ordered pair; Moreover, you need Replacement to show that if $f$ is a function with domain $J$ then the image-set $\{f(j):j\in J\}$ exists.

We obtain $P\cup Q$ by (1) Pairing: $R=\{P,Q\}$ exists. That is $\forall P,Q \,\exists R\, \forall S\,(S\in R\iff [S=P\lor S=Q])$, and then by (2) Union: If $R=\{P,Q\}$ then any $x\in \bigcup R \iff [x\in P\lor x\in Q].$